# Как песочные часы создать пустыми?

Tags: java

```java
class pir {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Введите (нечетное число) ширину песочных часов: ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i=1; i<=a; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j=1; j<=a; j++) {
                if (j>=i && j<=a-i+1 || j<=i && j>=a-i+1) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Непонятен вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, для создания пустых часов достаточно не выводить символ-заполнитель `*`, когда счетчик `j` находится "внутри" часов:

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = 1; j <= a; j++) {
        if (i == 1 || i == a // верхняя и нижняя линия часов
         || j == i || j == a - i + 1) { // контуры часов
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Результат (для `а = 11`):

```
***********
 *       * 
  *     *  
   *   *   
    * *    
     *     
    * *    
   *   *   
  *     *  
 *       * 
***********
```

для `a == 8`

```
********
 *    * 
  *  *  
   **   
   **   
  *  *  
 *    * 
********
```

Comment: Спасибо, лучший!!!